# overload the > operator (__gt__)

Tags: python

I want my `Book` class to overload the `>` operator `__gt__`. So, I can use it in my BookCollection to find the right order.

I used > in InsertBook(). But it is not working! How do I fix it? I want it to be ordered by

1. the Book’s author (alphabetical / lexicographical order)
2. the Book’s year of publication
3. the Book’s title (alphabetical / lexicographical order).

This is my current code for the class `Book.py`:

```py
    class Book:
        def __init__(self, title='', author='',year=None):
            self.title = title
            self.author = author
            self.year = year
        def setTitle(self, title):
            self.title = title
        def setAuthor(self, author):
            self.author = author
        def setYear(self, year):
            self.year = year
        def getTitle(self):
            return self.title
        def getAuthor(self):
            return self.author
        def getYear(self):
            return self.year
        def __gt__(self,item):
            if (0,1,0) > (0,0,0):
                return self.author > item.author
            else:
                return False
            if (1,0,0) > (0,0,0):
                return self.title > item.title
            else:
                return False
            if (0,0,1) > (0,0,0):
                return self.year > item.year
            else:
                return False
            
        def getBookDetails(self):
            return "Title: {}, Author: {}, Year: {}".format(self.title, self.author, self.year)
    

    

  
        class BookCollection():
        def __init__(self):
            self.head = None
        def isEmpty(self):
            return self.head == None
        def insertBook(self, book):
            current = self.head
            previous = None
            stop = False
            while current != None and not stop:
                if current.getData() > book:
                    stop = True
                else:
                    previous = current
                    current = current.getNext()
            temp = BookCollectionNode(book)
            if previous == None:
                temp.setNext(self.head)
                self.head = temp
            else:
                temp.setNext(current)
                previous.setNext(temp)
        def getNumberOfBooks(self):
            temp = self.head
            count = 0
            while temp != None:
                count = count + 1
                temp = temp.getNext()
            return count
        def getAllBooksInCollection(self):
            current = self.head
            output = ""
            while current != None:
                output += str(current.getData()) + " "
                current = current.getNext()
            output = output[:len(output)-1] + "\n"
            return output
        def getBooksByAuthor(self,item):
            current = self.head
            found = False
            stop = False
            while current != None and not found and not stop:
                if current.getData() == item:
                    found = True
                else:
                    if current.getData() > item:
                        stop = True
                    else:
                        current = current.getNext()
            return found
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you're question is, it seems like you know what and how to overload the __gt__ magic method, an you clarify what it is you're unclear on?

Comment: You're not "overloading" the operator, you're merely defining it on your class.  See any tutorial on the topic of defining standard operations on your own class.

Comment: There is  no actual question here, and improper code. This question is unlikely to be well received as it stands. Please fix.

Comment: Edited to (hopefully) make it more suitable for SO.

Answer (score 0):

> I used > in InsertBook(). But it is not working! How do I fix it? I want it to be ordered by

1. Your overload of the method makes no sense, why are you comparing completely static tuple values? That's always going to do the same thing, so your entire override is really just `return self.author > item.author`
2. Overriding `__gt__` alone is a bad idea: you really need to override them all or you'll get incoherent result. The [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) class decorator allows overriding just `__eq__` and one ordering operator, you probably want to use that.

> I want it to be ordered by
>
> ```
> the Book’s author (alphabetical / lexicographical order)
> the Book’s year of publication
> the Book’s title (alphabetical / lexicographical order).
> ```

Then compare that? I'd recommend a key method or property for simplicity e.g.

```py
@total_ordering
class Book:
    @property
    def _key(self):
        return (self.author, self.year, self.title)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._key == other._key
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self._key > other._key
```

should do the trick and order your records by ascending author, ascending year of publication, and ascending title

That aside,

#### Python is not Java

All your trivial getters and setters are useless and redundant, just remove them outright. And `getBookDetails` should just be the implementation of your `__str__`.

`BookCollection` is similarly concerning, `isEmpty` is not a thing in Python, instead collections implement `__len__` (and optionally `__bool__` for efficiency). And the entire thing is a mess, why doesn't `BookCollection` just contain a `list` of books (or some other collection from the stdlib)? What's the purpose of making it some sort of ad-hoc half-assed linked list?

And it shoudl provide (or use) an iterator, you're implementing the same iteration scheme 3 different times for no reason.

Your naming scheme is also incorrect, Python normally uses `snake_case` for methods, and properties, and fields.